# Shared database and "An owner referenced by user does not have EXECUTE PROCEDURE access to" procedure

Tags: teradata

Is there a way around it in Teradata, if you have rights to create a procedure in the shared database, but fail to execute the first procedure inside the second procedure you created in the same database.
Attempted with SQL INVOKER and SQL CREATOR.

Tried an option to grant the execution explicitly, ended with the:

> The user doesn't have CREATE PROCEDURE WITH GRANT OPTION access to database

What else can be done here?

```
.login server1/$user1,$pwd1
database shared_db;
replace proc proc1
SQL SECURITY CREATOR
begin
end;

replace proc proc2
begin
  call proc1;
end;

-- errors
```

EDIT for Fred:

Database holding the procedures is shared (aka shared_db). User1 (who has the rights to create procedures in the shared_db) is creating proc1 in it, and proc2; the latter executes proc1 from its body.

EDIT 2 - concluded, setup needed was indeed (which is not that obvious)

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON shared_db.proc1 to shared_db;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The creator of PROC1 can

```
 GRANT EXECUTE PROCEDURE ON shared_db.proc1 TO shared_db;
```

Comment: In my case this would be: (I am user1) GRANT EXECUTE PROCEDURE ON shared_db.proc1 TO user1; Grant comes through, compilation of proc2 still generates error 3523 (in the subject line).

Comment: No. With default DEFINER security for PROC2, the database containing PROC2 also needs the right to call PROC1. Please edit your question to clarify exactly what you are trying and what is failing.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for my case!